# How to read image from assets folder in android and make it available in view class

Tags: android, image, view

I am working on loading an image in a view.
please help me out!
For Example i have a code:

```
Class myView extends View

{

// I want to load image in to this view 

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this function in your extended `View` class. Pass file name as argument here.

```
private Bitmap getBitmapFromAsset(String strName)
    {
        AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
        InputStream istr = null;
        try {
            istr = assetManager.open(strName);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(istr);
        return bitmap;
    }
```